# Laravel вложенные отношения в модель

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, model, relation

Для того что бы получить список всех **users** вместе с **posts** которые принадлежат этим пользователям мы используем **hasMany** отношением.

Но как получить всех **users** вместе с их **posts** и вместе с **tags** для этих постов? **tags** (к примеру тоже **hasMany** но не суть)

И как это делать еще более глубже, выше описано 3 уровня, а как примеру сделать это с 5ю уровнями

Это необходимо для **API** как вытаскивать вместе с отношениями которые внутри других отношений

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подгрузки отношений (в том числе и вложенных) используйте метод with() билдера:

```
$users = User::with('posts.tags')->get();
```

Подробнее об использовании этого метода можно почитать [здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)